# How to display sequential ROW_NUMBER if duplicates ID's are not in a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I dont really know how to correctly explain my problem, I used subquery to bring only distinct ProducerCode field. 
But now I just need basically row identifier with sequence number, but when I use ROW_NUMBER function it gives me weird numbers.
Using SQL 2012, SSRS 2010 
Here is my code:

```
    ;WITH cte_Counts   --C
AS 
    (
        SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ProducerCode) as RowNum,
                    ProducerCode, 
                    ProducerName, 
                    COUNT (distinct ControlNo) as Submissions,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Quotes,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Status IN ('Bound','Cancelled','Notice of Cancellation','Non-Renewed') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Binds,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN  Status = 'Declined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as  Declines
        FROM        ClearanceReportMetrics
        WHERE       YEAR(EffectiveDate)=2016
                    AND CompanyLine = 'Arch Insurance Company'
        GROUP BY    ProducerCode,ProducerName
    )

SELECT   * FROM 
            (
                SELECT  RowNum,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProducerCode ORDER BY Submissions  DESC) as num,
                        ProducerCode,
                        ProducerName as 'Producer',         
                        Submissions,
                        Quotes,
                        Binds,
                        Declines,
                        COALESCE(CAST(Binds as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Submissions,0),0) as 'Sub. to Bind',
                        COALESCE(CAST(Quotes as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Submissions,0),0) as 'Sub. to Qt',
                        COALESCE(CAST(Binds as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Quotes,0),0) as 'Qt to Bind',
                        COALESCE(CAST(Declines as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Submissions,0),0) as 'Sub to Dec'

                FROM    cte_Counts
                    ) a 
WHERE a.num=1               
ORDER BY    
            Submissions DESC
```

[image]

I tried to achieve that in SSRS with expression

```
=RowNumber(Nothing)
```

But it skips numbers as well:
[image]

How can I display just sequence row number?

Comment: Try `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) as RowNum`. Also note the outer order by is unsorting values in cte's RowNum column. Additional filters in your dataset or tablix will brake the sequence.

Comment: I took off the last Order By and used `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) as RowNum`  but sequence is still broken

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code once and let me if any questions

```
 ;WITH cte_Counts   --C
AS 
    (
        SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ProducerCode) as RowNum,
                    ProducerCode, 
                    ProducerName, 
                    COUNT (distinct ControlNo) as Submissions,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Quotes,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Status IN ('Bound','Cancelled','Notice of Cancellation','Non-Renewed') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Binds,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN  Status = 'Declined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as  Declines
        FROM        ClearanceReportMetrics
        WHERE       YEAR(EffectiveDate)=2016
                    AND CompanyLine = 'Arch Insurance Company'
        GROUP BY    ProducerCode,ProducerName
    )

    Select * FROM
    (

SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ProducerCode) AS NEW_ROW_NUMBER,* FROM 
            (
                SELECT  RowNum,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProducerCode ORDER BY Submissions  DESC) as num,
                        ProducerCode,
                        ProducerName as 'Producer',         
                        Submissions,
                        Quotes,
                        Binds,
                        Declines,
                        COALESCE(CAST(Binds as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Submissions,0),0) as 'Sub. to Bind',
                        COALESCE(CAST(Quotes as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Submissions,0),0) as 'Sub. to Qt',
                        COALESCE(CAST(Binds as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Quotes,0),0) as 'Qt to Bind',
                        COALESCE(CAST(Declines as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Submissions,0),0) as 'Sub to Dec'

                FROM    cte_Counts
                    ) a 
WHERE a.num=1     
)     A     
ORDER BY    
            Submissions DESC
```

Comment: `NEW_ROW_NUMBER` column is not in order. If at the end I say `ORDER BY NEW_ROW_NUM` then it works. But then it wont be sorted by Submissions

Answer (score 0):

You should only need the one `ROW_NUMBER()` as you are already getting a distinct list of Producer Codes and Names in your `CTE` via the `GROUP BY`:

```
    ;WITH cte_Counts   --C
AS 
    (
        SELECT      ProducerCode, 
                    ProducerName, 
                    COUNT (distinct ControlNo) as Submissions,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Quotes,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Status IN ('Bound','Cancelled','Notice of Cancellation','Non-Renewed') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Binds,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN  Status = 'Declined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as  Declines
        FROM        ClearanceReportMetrics
        WHERE       YEAR(EffectiveDate)=2016
                    AND CompanyLine = 'Arch Insurance Company'
        GROUP BY    ProducerCode,ProducerName
    )

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Submissions DESC) as RowNum,
        *
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT  ProducerCode,
                        ProducerName as 'Producer',         
                        Submissions,
                        Quotes,
                        Binds,
                        Declines,
                        COALESCE(CAST(Binds as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Submissions,0),0) as 'Sub. to Bind',
                        COALESCE(CAST(Quotes as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Submissions,0),0) as 'Sub. to Qt',
                        COALESCE(CAST(Binds as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Quotes,0),0) as 'Qt to Bind',
                        COALESCE(CAST(Declines as FLOAT) /NULLIF(Submissions,0),0) as 'Sub to Dec'

                FROM    cte_Counts
                    ) a           
ORDER BY    RowNum
```